# Can't get GNUradio PLL Frequency Detector to work

Tags: gnuradio, pll

I am trying to implement doppler logging of the carrier frequency of a phase modulated satellite downlink signal. I tried implementing this using the "PLL Frequency Detector" block in GNUradio.

I re-created the example from [PLL Frequency Detector](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=PLL_Frequency_Detector) as a starting point and noticed that it does not work as expected. The output of this block into the Number Sink and Time Sink seems to indicate that the PLL hasn't locked successfully (changing the input freq, also near the center frequency, doesnt seem to result in carrier tracking). I changed various variables like loop bandwidth and Min/Max frequency, but I am having no success so far getting this to work.

What is the mistake I am making? Is the block broken? Any pointers on how to get this to work would be much appreciated.

I am running GNUradio 3.10.4.0 (Python 3.10.6) under Windows 10.

[image: Flowgraph used]

[image: GUI output]

Comment: your loop bandwidth makes no sense to me. Could you explain your choice?

Comment: The 0.314159 value is given in the usage example: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=PLL_Frequency_Detector
I also tried pi/200 2pi/100 (which is suggested also on that page) but it also does not work.

Comment: ah wait. let's start with the beginning: Your sample rate is 100e3; your signal frequency is 100e3. What does the signal look like? (do a bit of math on paper ;) it's a single line involving $e^{j 2 \pi …}$

Comment: No, the signal frequency is 1 Hz at startup (when it doesnt lock). Also varying the signal frequency over a range of +-50kHz it does not lock. Nyquist wise that should be fine, right? (Or I am not getting the hint :))

Comment: yep, that'd be fine :) got me there! Ok, so let's talk a bit about what these values in the loop bandwidth and min/max frequency really mean: they are frequencies, but specified in "how much does the phase change per sample, at most". So, right now you're OK with the phase changing to the complete opposite every sample in case of the maximum and minimum frequencies – that will however make it harder for the PLL to initially lock. The bandwidth is the same: When designing a low-pass filter for the phase error *change*, how wide should it be. Go with much smaller values!

Comment: OK, could you suggest what values should work? I tried now significantly smaller values for the loop bandwidth but I still cant get it to lock. (I kinda expected the example from the website also to work out of the box, which is not the case, which makes me wonder if maybe this block is broken nowadays)

Comment: yeah, I can understand that; I'm sorry, can currently not go off and reproduce.

Comment: No problem! If you do get a chance to check it still, it would be much appreciated.